# Keep the data in Ionic provider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm making an API request with Ionic 3, and displaying it on a page **Home.ts**, using a Provider.
I need the data to remain in the provider after the first request, so that all pages that uses this Provider can access the same information without having to re-request the API. What is the best way to do this?

Versions: ionic CLI: 3.10;
Ionic Framework: 3.7.1

---

**people-service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class PeopleServiceProvider {
  requisicao: any;
  films: Observable<any>;
  //getApiUrl : string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  getApiUrl : string = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=3";


  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.requisicao = null;
  }

  // returns a Observable
  getHTTP(docache: boolean) {
      return this.http.get(this.getApiUrl)
              .do(res  => console.log(res.json()))
              .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

---

**Home.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {PeopleServiceProvider} from '../../providers/people-service/people-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [PeopleServiceProvider]
})
export class HomePage {

  films: Observable<any>;
  public people: any;
  req: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loading: LoadingController, public peopleService: PeopleServiceProvider) {
    this.people = null;
  }

  loadPeople(docache:boolean) {

      let loader = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Wait...',
      });

      loader.present().then(() => {
        this.req = this.peopleService.getHTTP(docache);
        this.req.subscribe((data)=>{
            this.people = data.results;
            console.log(this.people);
        });
        // this.peopleService.getPosts(docache);

        loader.dismiss();

      });

  }
}
```

---

**Home.html**

```
  <button ion-button secondary (click)='loadPeople(true);'>Do cache</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

You can easily use [**storage module**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) for that.

> Storage is an easy way to store key/value pairs and JSON objects.
>   Storage uses a variety of storage engines underneath, picking the best
>   one available depending on the platform.

```
 // set a key/value
  storage.set('name', 'myName');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('name').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your name is', val);
  });
```

**Method 2:**

If you need to expire that value at some point then you can use [**Ionic cache service**](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache)

Great article about [**it is here**](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-caching-service/).

Comment: Although it should be noted that this will actually cache it even across page visits. That may or may not be what one wants, in any case you should think about cache expiry here.

Comment: On the [Ionic cache article](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-caching-service/) you've shared, at file **src/pages/home/home.ts **, lines 20-25 `let req = this.http.get(url) ...` it seems that the data will always hit the API server before show the cached result, isn't it?

Comment: No.It does only once.After that, it uses cached data until it'll be expired.I have used this API and it is really awesome one.

Comment: How can I put a LoadingController in the article example? to give the user a feedback that the data is loading when press Load Films button

Comment: What is the problem there? You just need to implement this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/

Comment: that article is now behind a paywall

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
.publishReplay(1)
.refCount();
```

On your http request observable.
publishReplay caches the most recent value. reCount keeps the observable alive until there are no more observer.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result in a class member of the provider. The provider's life cycle is dependent on who is providing it: just move it from the `providers` of a specific page to the `providers` of your app module. This way, it will stay alive as long as the app is alive.

Comment: What do you mean about move the `providers` of a specific page to the `providers` of app module? I thought that **people-service.ts** is already a **public** provider that all the pages can access this, isn't? Can you show a example of app module provider?

Comment: Currently, you provide the service in the decorator of `HomePage`, which means the service is scoped to that component. If you provide it in your AppModule instead, it is scoped to the entire app, which means any data you store in the service are kept for the app's entire lifecycle.